# alter table modify column which is a foreign key

Tags: mysql, constraints

I am using mysql:8.0.2

I have a table column defined as below:

```
create table test (
 my_code        VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

This table.column is a foriegn key to many other tables. I would like to change the character set of the table to ascii with the following command:

```
alter table test modify my_code VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_general_ci  NOT NULL;
```

This leads to error because of the foreign keys. I do not want to disable the foreign key checks. I know I can go to each individual table and alter it manually. However, that is very cumbersome as this has multiple levels of foreign key constraints. How do I cascade the changes to all the tables downstream?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to solve this without disabling FK checks. All the columns have to have the same datatype, so you have to alter all the tables. There's no way to do them all at once, so you have to disable checks, alter each table individually, then re-enable FK checks.

Comment: There's nothing that automatically cascades datatype changes to foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

And, "same datatype", includes `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION` for strings.

Beware:  There are several ways of converting the charset/collation of a column.  Most techniques mangle the existing data.  So...

What is currently in the column?  If it is just English letters, then `ALTER TABLE ... CONVERT TO ...` is the appropriate technique.

If the column currently contains non-English accented letters, etc., then we need to dig deeper.  We won't be able to convert to Ascii without making a big mess.

If there is only Ascii characters in the column, then why bother altering the `CHARACTER SET`?  Sure there are reasons, but tell us the reason so we can say whether it is worth the hassle that you are facing.

By the way, 8.0.2 was pre-release.  You should really upgrade to a newer ("GA") version.  This upgrade may avoid related problems that you have not yet stumbled over.

I am not a fan of FKs.  You have encountered yet another reason why they are more hassle than benefit.

I do not know if you can simply disable FKs, convert all the table, then re-enable them.  Or whether you must remove the FKs and reestablish them.  In any case, it is a big hassle.